# branch io clicked_branch_link is false

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io

I have integrated branch.io deep linking in my iOS app (Swift 4.2). What I want is canonical_url when user taps on branch.io short link.

When app is running in background I get all required parameters in following block. but when app is not running and try to tap branch.io short link then app launches but I do not get required parameters even clicked_branch_link is false.

```
Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) 
{ (params, error) in

    print(params as? [String: AnyObject] ?? {})
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let userDidClick = params?["+clicked_branch_link"] as? Bool else { return }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you have all the basic implementation code as shown in our docs here: https://branchmetrics.github.io/docs/pages/apps/ios/#initialize-branch.

In addition, you can find a working implementation of the Swift Branch SDK in our Testbed application here: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking/tree/master/Branch-TestBed-Swift.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented everything as per documents. It launches app when I tap on link. When app is running background value of +clicked_branch_link is TRUE
But when app is not running then app launches properly but +clicked_branch_link is FALSE